# VS2013 - SQL Server Server Project Options

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, database-project

In VS 2010, you had the ability to create a "SQL Server 2008 Server Project" which would be used to contain the logins, linked server, etc for your SQL Server.  Then in your Database projects, you would be able to reference the server project which would remove some of the unresolved references when dealing with permissions.  It allowed for a single place to contain the shared server data for numerous projects.  Does this capability exist in VS 2013?  The only project option that I current have for SQL is "SQL Server Database Project".  If not, does it mean you need to keep login information in each database project that shares the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no equivalent of the Server Project in Visual Studio 2013 (specifically, SQL Server Data Tools). The server-level objects (logins, linked servers, etc.) are supposed to be scripted in each project.

If you have server-level objects referenced by multiple database projects then one option is to script that object in each project preceded by existence checks. (Ouch.)

Another option is to include a shared script in each project's post-deployment script, for example:

```
:r ..\..\SharedScripts\Logins.sql
:r ..\..\SharedScripts\LinkedServers.sql
```

However this 2nd option won't work in all situations. Depending on how the object is referenced you will get an "unresolved reference" error that will prevent your project from building.

Comment: Keith, thanks for the info despite how disappointing it is.  I wonder if there was a specific reasoning on why MS went away from that methodology.  I liked how that worked previously and it kept the common items in a shared location, as I would expect them from a development standpoint.